# Nao executa o server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Esta dando este erro depois de `npm run dev`
(ja instalei o mongo e os modelos npm que necessita)

> npm ERR! missing script: dev
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\Getin-sds\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-11-29T19_11_17_439Z-debug.log

Segue o codigo do server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const uri = "mongodb://Carlos-Antonio:ca102030@ds237735.mlab.com:37735/meubanco"

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

MongoClient.connect(uri, (err, client) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    db = client.db('meubanco')
    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log('Servidor está rodando na porta 3000.')
    })
})

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.route('/')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        const cursor = db.collection('data').find()
        res.render('index.ejs')
    })

    .post((req, res) => {
        db.collection('data').save(req.body, (err, result) => {
            if (err) return console.log(err)

            console.log('Dados gravados com sucesso.')
            res.redirect('/show')
        })
    })

app.route('/show')
    .get((req, res) => {
        db.collection('data').find().toArray((err, results) => {
            if (err) return console.log(err)
            res.render('show.ejs', { data: results })
        })
    })

app.route('/edit/:id')
    .get((req, res) => {
        var id = req.params.id

        db.collection('data').find(ObjectId(id)).toArray((err, result) => {
            if (err) return res.send(err)
            res.render('edit.ejs', { data: result })
        })
    })
    .post((req, res) => {
        var id = req.params.id
        var nome = req.body.nome
        var sobrenome = req.body.sobrenome

        db.collection('data').updateOne({ _id: ObjectId(id) }, {
            $set: {
                nome: nome,
                sobrenome: sobrenome
            }
        }, (err, result) => {
            if (err) return res.send(err)
            res.redirect('/show')
            console.log('Dados atualizados com sucesso.')
        })
    })

app.route('/delete/:id')
    .get((req, res) => {
        var id = req.params.id
        db.collection('data').deleteOne({ _id: ObjectId(id) }, (err, result) => {
            if (err) return res.send(500, err)
            console.log('Dado excluído com sucesso.')
            res.redirect('/show')
        })
    })
```

esta aqui o arquivo onde coloco

```
{
  "name": "projeto",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: Boa tarde, está ausente do arquivo `package.json` que fica na raiz do seu projeto o script `dev` que executa o arquivo `serve.js`. Entre la e apenas adicione `"dev": "node serve.js"` e salve que o `npm run dev` deve funcionar, mas isso se o serve.js estiver na mesma pasta que o package.json se não é necessario por o caminho do serve.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O comando `npm run` é um alias para o comando [`npm run-script <comando>`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) que indica qual o script da propriedade `scripts` do `package.json` será executado.

No seu caso você está executando com o comando `dev` que não está definido nas propriedades. Você pode adicioná-lo ou executar o comando `npm run start` ao invés disso.

Comment: Valeu pelas dicas agora consegui executar certo